# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 1, Question 19a

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329759/michael-spivaks-calculus-chapter-1-problem-19/1868127#1868127) as solution to the question. Here's a quote for easy reference.

> Supposing $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not both $0$, and that there is no number $\lambda$ such that $x_1=\lambda y_1$ and $x_2=\lambda y_2$, then $$\begin{array}{tcl}0 &<& (\lambda y_1-x_1)^2 + (\lambda y_2-x_2)^2 \\ &=& \lambda^2 (y_1^2+y_2^2)-2\lambda(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)+(x_1^2+x_2^2),\end{array}$$ and the equation $$\lambda^2 (y_1^2+y_2^2)-2\lambda(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)+(x_1^2+x_2^2)=0 \\$$
> has *no* solution $\lambda$. So by problem 18(a) we must have $$\Bigg[\frac{2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)}{({y_1}^2+{y_2}^2)}\Bigg]^2-\frac{4({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2)}{({y_1}^2+{y_2}^2)} < 0,****** \\$$ which yields the Schwarz inequality.

Notice the heavily asterisked line. I don't understand how we derive this. I recognize that this is "completing the square." Question 18 emphasized that $b^2 - 4c < 0$ means $x^2 + bx + c > 0$. Except, in this problem, it's not clear why he choose the $b$ the way he did. Where does the 2 come from? In the sense that, isn't $b = \frac{-2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)}{({y_1}^2+{y_2}^2)}$.

Comment: Well, he just divided everywhere by $a=(y_1^2+y_2^2)$. The discriminant is $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ so he just divided by $a$ to simplify. Don't forget the polynomial is in lambda, so everything else are just coefficients. Hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Top equation ends on $x_1^2+x_2^2$ but the middle equation has $x_1^2 + {y_1^2}^*$, which one is correct, please clarify?

Comment: @gt6989b I edited the original post for clarity. Hopefully this should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REMARK** Your top equation ends on $x_1^2+x_2^2$ but the middle equation has $x_1^2 + {y_1^2}^*$, which one is correct, please clarify? Assuming the second one is really intended and the first is a typo.

---

You yourself quote that $b^2-4c<0 \iff x^2 + bx + c > 0$. You have the equation
$$
\lambda^2 (y_1^2+y_2^2)-2\lambda(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)+(x_1^2+{y_1^2}^*)=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\lambda^2
-\left(2 \frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{y_1^2+y_2^2} \right) \lambda
 + \frac{x_1^2+{y_1^2}^*}{y_1^2+y_2^2}
 = 0
$$
So choosing
$$
b = -2 \frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{y_1^2+y_2^2},
c = \frac{x_1^2+{y_1^2}^*}{y_1^2+y_2^2}
$$
and plugging into $b^2-4c < 0$ will give you the result you are seeking. Note that the sign of $b$ makes no difference here since you are only looking at $b^2$.

Comment: I understand clearly now. The sign of $b$ confused me. When transforming this into the Schwarz Inequality I had to take a root of both sides and the negative sign in front of the 2 wasn't handled properly. Thanks so much!