# Chapter 1 Question 19(a)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation

To put this in context, the question deals with the "great-granddaddy" of all inequalities, viz  ${x}_{1}{y}_{1} + {x}_{2}{y}_{2} \le \sqrt{{x}_{1}^{2} + {x}_{2}^{2}}\sqrt{{y}_{1}^{2} + {y}_{2}^{2}}$

Part 3 of the multipart question, as follows.

> Now suppose that $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are not both $0$, and that there is no number $\lambda$ such that $x_{1} = \lambda y_{1}$ and $x_{2} = \lambda y_{2}$ then
>
> $0 < (\lambda y_{1} - x_{1})^{2} + (\lambda y_{2} - x_{2})^{2} = \lambda^{2}.....$

There have been many questions regarding parts of the questions and [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691853/spivaks-calculus-chapter-1-question-19a)

My confusion is how Spivak derives

$0 < (\lambda y_{1} - x_{1})^{2} + (\lambda y_{2} - x_{2})^{2}  $

All other aspects of this question are well covered.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $0\leqslant(\lambda y_1-x_1)^2+(\lambda y_2-x_2)^2$. And if we had the equality here, that would mean that $\lambda y_1-x_1=\lambda y_2-x_2=0$. But we are assuming that there is no such $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you. Perfectly put.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume $x_1 \neq \lambda y_1$.

$x_1-\lambda y_1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow (x_1-\lambda y_1)^2 \neq 0 \Rightarrow (x_1-\lambda y_1)^2>0$

$(x_1-\lambda y_1)^2 >0$, and  $(x_2-\lambda y_2)^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow (x_1-\lambda y_1)^2 + (x_2-\lambda y_2)^2 > 0$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.